# Android Mediaplayer play Local Files with Variable

Tags: android, json, media-player, local

wondering if anyone can help me figure out how to play local audio/video files in Android Mediaplayer...I am able to stream audio/video from URL's using a Variable holding the URL address  but how to do it with local files? How to use the localFile variable to call local Files to play? thanks everyone!

```
package com.ryanleckey2;






import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;


public class Audio_Video_Stream extends  BT_activity_base{


    private String localFile = "";
    private String localFileName = "";
    private String dataURL = "";
    private String currentURL = "";
    public String thisActivityName = "Screen_Video";

    //movie controller
    String videoUrl;
    VideoView videoView;
    MediaController mediaController;
    public int isLoading;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.screen_video);



        //fill JSON properties...
        dataURL = BT_strings.getJsonPropertyValue(this.screenData.getJsonObject(), "dataURL", "");
        currentURL = dataURL;

        localFileName = BT_strings.getJsonPropertyValue(this.screenData.getJsonObject(), "localFileName", "");


                //setup the saveAsFileName
                if(localFileName.length() > 1){

                    //use the file name in the JSON data...
                localFile = localFileName;  





        //Log.i("ZZ", thisActivityName + ":videoUrl : " + videoUrl);   

        videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
        isLoading = 0;
        }

    }   










    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //activity life-cycle overrides

    //onStart
    @Override 
    protected void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        //Log.i("ZZ", thisActivityName + ":onStart");
    }

    //onResume
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if(isLoading == 1){
            if(videoView != null){
                videoView = null;
            }
        }
        startMovie();
        //Log.i("ZZ", thisActivityName + ":onResume");
    }

    //onPause
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        //Log.i("ZZ", thisActivityName + ":onPause");
        super.onPause();

        if(videoView != null){
            videoView = null;
        }
    }

    //onStop
    @Override 
    protected void onStop(){
        super.onStop();

        //Log.i("ZZ", thisActivityName + ":onStop");
    }   

    //onDestroy
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        //Log.i("ZZ", thisActivityName + ":onDestroy");
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    //activity life-cycle overrides
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////


    //starts movie
    public void startMovie(){

        //show progress for a few seconds..
        showProgress("Starting media stream...", "Please be patient. If you're on 3G this could take a bit.\nWi-Fi is much better for streaming.");
        isLoading = 1;

        try{
            //set audio/video link (mp4,mp3 format )
            mediaController = new MediaController(this);
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(currentURL);
            //Uri       uri=Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.);  
            videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
            videoView.setVideoURI(uri);        
            videoView.setOnPreparedListener(mOnPreparedListener);

            videoView.start();

        }catch(Exception je){
        hideProgress();
            showAlert("Invalid URL","The URL to the media could not be determined. This screen will close.");
            finish();
        }

    }

    //onPrepared...
    private MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener mOnPreparedListener = new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener(){
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp){
            //Log.i("ZZ", thisActivityName + ":OnPreparedListener");
            isLoading = 0;
        //  mp.setLooping(true);
        hideProgress();
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Im using **media player** to play a local **audio** file located in my assets folder. Here is a snippet of my code. Let me know if you need help implementing. These lines of code are inside of a try method.

**UPDATE** Ok I'm taking a shot in the dark here, but lets see if you can switch your try method with mine. First, use this import:

`import android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor;`

Now, inside of your "try" brackets, try this:

```java
 AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd("YOURSOUNDORVIDEO.mp3/mpg");  
 mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength()); 
 mp.prepare();
 mp.start(); //play sound or video
```

In my code, mp stands for mediaplayer. Change it to whatever you used to describe your local file or player and see if it works. Android will tell you whats wrong if theres a problem. If it doesn't then we'll need expertise. But you can't blame a noob gal for trying, eh?

Comment: Hi, yes definitely need help implementing...what happens is an online  control panel builds the Json telling the app what to display...so if I have this variable for a local file and the local file is in the assets folder, how to connect this together? Very new and grateful for ur help!

Comment: Crud..you didnt mention Json before lol..I dont know what the hello world that is, never worked with it before. Hang in there while I look for a solution to your "special" problem :)

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate you help...maybe i'm in over my head being so new to all this...standing by :)

Comment: I agree lol. You should make it simple. Why use Json and variables when you can have a built in audio / movie player? I know absolutely nothing about Json. If you can get that code to work in your code, I applaud you. All I know is "That" is how you play a local file. lol.

Comment: I'll tell you upfront though - your question needs to be answered by a senior developer. By senior, I mean not noobs like we are :p At least no one can point fingers at me because im a girl and we can make mistakes:)

Comment: Cool, thanks for your time...I will keep working this and post what i find...thanks for your suggestions they will definitely come in handy! :)

Comment: Well, if you ever want to play media without Json, you know where to find me lol. Im actually using a webview to play mine.

Comment: Ha! Thanks, yes i was using a webview as well, then i opened up this can of worms :)

Comment: lmao you should go back to whats simple. You can always customize the xml to get it to look super hawt. Im using a local webview with jquerymobile (extracted the zip into my assets),so it looks professional. Plus, I got the media player on top of the webview and I tell ya...after all the time it took me to even learn how to do webview and local media playback, im not budging for now lol